# SharePoint Solution Permissions and Server Object Model (SSOM)

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, web-part, solution

I have to build a simple full trusted SharePoint Solution with a webpart. When a user clicks a button in this webpart, I want to change some data in a list, to which he has only read-only permissions. However, when I try to do it, SharePoint gives me a page with a message: "User access denied". 
When I try the same scenario with a user who has a write access to that list, everything works.

My question is, why does full trusted SharePoint solution does not have an access to write to a SharePoint list when the user does not and vice versa? Is there any permission setting I need to set for that solution?

I am using SSOM, something like this: 
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sharepoint/sharepoint_server_object_model.htm

Thank you for your ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the method "RunWithElevatedPrivileges", should work.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges.aspx

Example:

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
  //Your code here
});
```

Comment: very cool! thank you so much. I will try it in few hours and let you know if this works! :)

Comment: I had to add this before running the command

                    oSite.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                    oWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

Answer (score 1):

Full-trust farm solutions execute without any **code access security restrictions** , but this doesn't mean it override the users permissions by default,

you can use  `SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges method` to Executes the specified actions with Full Control rights even if the user does not otherwise have Full Control.

[SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges.aspx)

Comment: very cool! thank you so much. I will try it in few hours and let you know if this works! :)

Comment: @Pedro  good , please do that :)

Comment: awesome, it worked. I had to add this before I ran the command and then I turned it back off
oSite.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                    oWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;